# How to make one project compiled on xcode5 and xcode6 by using different apis？

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, ios8, xcode6

Hello，everyone。

my project need to be compiled on Xcode5 using iOS7 SDK and on compiled on Xcode6 using iOS8 SDK at the same time，but some header file like "opengles／gltypes.h" only appears in iOS8 SDK。

When I compile my project using Xcode5，the compiler complains that the opengles／gltypes.h file not found。

Is it this problem solvable？ How to fix it？

Thanks a lot！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code that should only be compiled under Xcode 6 with a Base SDK of iOS 8 should be wrapped with:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
    // Base SDK of iOS 8
#endif
```

Anything in between will be ignored if the Base SDK is iOS 7 or earlier (such as when using Xcode 5).

Note that the above is a compile time check. You may need additional runtime checks if you need to support both iOS 7 and iOS 8 while using Xcode 6.